# AWS/SSM/AWS-RunPatchBaseline

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssm

I'm in the process of exploring AWS SSM to apply Patches on multiple AWS accounts. I was able to implement this successfully using respective AWS documents. During my implementation process, I used AWS-RunPatchBaseline document to update my linux instances.

This completely works fine. Post patch installation the instance reboots. The use case which i'm trying to achieve is:

1. Instance should not reboot after installing patches.
   I tried to alter the document to disable reboot process, which did not help me. Also, checked with Amazon Support, they still in the process getting a fix for my request.

Does one have answer for this, either through using a custom document or by modifying the existing document?

Thanks,
Vick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per amazon we cannot stop or suspend the reboot post patching which is not advisable. However, Amazon is working on a feature request to suspend instance reboot. Wish it happens soon.